# Unblocking all processes waiting on a semaphore

Tags: linux, multithreading, locking, semaphore, race-condition

I have a program that requires several processes access a shared resource. This shared resource does not exist when they all start, so one of them needs to create it. Once the shared resource is created, important infrastructure is installed for use later. There is, however, a possibility that if the "creator" process is scheduled out **before** it can install the infrastructure in the shared resource, that other processes will try to use the uninitialized data (leading to undefined behavior).

In order to control this, I've created a **named** semaphore (`sem_t *sem_init`). Any process that is not the creator "downs" or "waits" on this zero-initialized semaphore. When the creator process has finished setup, it "up's" or "posts" the semaphore, releasing the processes. However, there remains one problem. **I do not know exactly how many processes are waiting on it**.

---

In order to solve this problem, I have the following options:

1. I create a **counting semaphore**. Each process "up's" or "posts" on this semaphore before blocking on the initialization semaphore. This way, I can know how many processes to release.
2. I just "post" on the initialization semaphore until it is the maximum allowed value.

---

I don't like these "solutions" though. For one, I am limited by the maximum size of a semaphore when it comes to the number of processes that I can count. It also seems like "posting" so many times would incur a nasty overhead. My question then, is whether there is any way in which I can instruct a semaphore to release **all** blocked processes, without me having to do any explicit bookkeeping on my end. I'd also not like to be constrained by the maximum value of a semaphore.

Something like: `sem_releaseAll (sem_t *sem_p);` would be ideal.

**Note:** I would greatly prefer a Linux-native solution.

Comment: Seems as if the resource being created was some kind of service. Hove you considered implementing it that way, using e.g. ZeroMQ as IPC framework? The framework makes sure requests are transmitted, even if it first has to wait for the receiver to start up.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt The process which creates the resource also forks a server which writes some data the other processes need (hence the requirement that they wait). That includes the port at which the server will listen. I suppose I could possibly continually attempt to connect to the address in shared memory until it succeeded with each process (like busy-waiting with a timeout). I think I will do something like that if I can't do what I want with semaphores. But I wanted to know if there was already a simpler solution with semaphores built in. Otherwise the question is more or less skirted.